# Problem with concatenation + itoa

Tags: c, string, strcat, itoa

I have the following code:

```
char stringHour[50], stringMinute[50], stringSecond[50];

// lots of code...
itoa(hour, stringHour, 10);
itoa(minute, stringMinute, 10);
itoa(second, stringSecond, 10);

strcat(":", stringSecond);
strcat(":", stringMinute);
strcat(stringMinute, stringSecond);
// stringHour contains both HH and :SS:MM
strcat(stringHour, stringMinute);
drawText(HRES/2 - 4, VRES - GLYPH_HEIGHT*2, 
stringHour, black);
```

`hour`, `minute` and `second` are all ints.

What I want to do is diplay time as follows: HH:MM:SS.

The variables are guaranteed to be between 0 and 59 (except hout, 0-24).

drawText is correct.

This block of code crashes my program, and I can't find anything wrong with it. Can you?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: For one thing, you are trying to be way too clever.  With the calls to `strcat` and `itoa` all nested like that, it's all but impossible to see what's going on.  Break them up into multiple statements so that it is clear what you are doing.

Comment: Agreed. Clarified intent with a comment underneath the block.

Comment: No, no.  A comment is The Wrong Solution to this complexity problem.  Make the code less complex by breaking it up into several, easy to comprehend statements.

Comment: I meant I commented my question right here :P But you're right, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely the bit that is failing is this piece:

```
... stuff removed
strcat (":", 
... other stuff removed
```

You almost certainly can't `strcat` stuff onto a string literal on the platform you are using.

The `strcat` approach has buffer overflow safety issues as well.  Maybe using `snprintf` might be a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
strcat(":", stringSecond);
```

You can't use a string literal for the first argument. See [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) doc.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it is best to init arrays to zero.

```
char stringHour[50] = {0}, stringMinute[50] = {0}, stringSecond[50] = {0};
```

Then try storing the result of the cat into a string to see what you come up with.

Comment: Also, `itoa` will not pad your numbers to 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify string literals; use `char buffer[] = "MyLiteral"` instead and then `strcat()` to that.

(The reason behind this fact is that the compiler can optimize code size by consolidating multiple instances of your string literals into one instance in a read-only section of the executable, and so if you could change one instance, you'd change everything else, which would result in unpredictable behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

Also - your strcat is in reverse order.  strcat actually "concatenates" - so change the order.
strcat(stringHour, ":");
strcat(stringHour, stringMinute);
strcat(stringHour, ":");
strcat(stringHour, stringSecond);

However, this is pretty terrible - why not use sprintf?  Also - other libraries except for string building - possibly look into the BSL.  The C standard library actually has no error checking for you either - so it's a shoot yourself in the foot, unless you know exactly what you're doing and what is expected from the str* family of functions.